# hello world app - learning developing for iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode

I was looking for some tutorials which use xCode 4. I found this [one](http://paulpeelen.com/2011/03/17/xcode-4-ios-4-3-hello-world/) but it didn't look as my xCode.
For example:
1) when I wish to make a new project, I don't find "View-based Application" option, just Single View Application. For the moment I've used single View Application.
2) The generated project doesn't contain "HelloWorldViewController.xib" file, so I've added it from new file.

Now, when I'm File's Owner I can't choose the right function("changeTheTextOfTheLabel") , because I don't see it between the options.

Can you give me your advice in order to finish my first HelloWorld app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple provides tutorials that are more likely to be a match for your tools if you're using the latest versions.  The following may help:

[Your first iOS application](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iPhone101/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007514-CH1-SW1)

[Your second iOS app](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011318-CH1-SW1)

Trying to adapt earlier approaches to the new templates and structure can be done but it can also be very frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider following [Apple's guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/Introduction/Introduction.html)

From the third page of that guide, they link to a [Hello World Tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/JumpRightIn/iPhone101/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-TP40007514)

After you've done that, the following course on iTunes-U is *very* good: http://itunes.apple.com/us/itunes-u/ipad-iphone-application-development/id473757255

Answer (score 1):

May be you are looking at xcode 3's example

but don't worry

If you are using xcode 4.2+

single view = view based

and if remove tick (check mark) for story board and you can find ViewController.xib

which is your HelloWorldViewController.xib